# SSRS Page footer Date Range

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

> How can I show date range for my SSRS report without passing the
>   parameter? I run an invoice between 1/1/2018 to 7/30/2018 & I need to
>   show this date range in the page footer.

Comment: The easiest way is to ensure those numbers appear in your results. Then use an expression MIN(Date) to MAX(DATE) basically.

Comment: But it will only give us Min date & Max date of the dataset right. It doesn't give us the exact values what we passed.

Comment: How does your report know what to filter for if you are not passing a parameter? If you're hard-coding the values in the query, add a start and end date column with your hard-coded values.

Comment: How do you determine the date range?

Comment: I'm using a software tool, which will determine daterange

Comment: @nmcsr one way to cheat, is simply include 2 more columns in your data set, one for the min and one for the max. You can ignore them in your report except where you want them.

Comment: What I mean is, you said you wanted to run an invoice report for a certain date range. How does you query determine what that date range actually is? I'm assuming some kind of parameter passed to a query or stored procedure, in which case we could use those values and return them in your dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the report has actual parameters (populated by whatever means) you should be able to use in a text box in your footer.

```
=Parameters!MinDate.Label & " " & Parameters!MaxDate.Label
```

or

```
=Parameters!MinDate.Value & " " & Parameters!MaxDate.Value
```